# sql server designing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to design a following kind of a scenario in sql server. can some one help me plz

```
tblOrderForm(OrderFormID int Auto Increment,OrderFormNO)
```

one order form has many

```
tblmobiles(mobileID int Auto Increment,Imie No)
```

and one order form has many

```
tblCustomers(CusID  int Auto Increment,Code)
```

Comment: If you want people to do your work completely for you, you typically have to pay.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables structure should be

```
tblOrderForm(OrderFormID int Auto Increment,OrderFormNO)
tblmobiles(OrderFormID int, mobileID int Auto Increment,Imie No varchar(20))
tblCustomers(OrderFormID int, CusID int Auto Increment,Code)
```

This supports your requirement.